# Converting "random" dice program into a class

Tags: c#, class, object, random

I am learning C# for a new position, and to try and understand classes better, I've written a short die-rolling tool to help me.  The code essentially rolls four d6, adds the total, and subtracts the smallest die roll.  The code is generated through a form, and the form shows all the rolled values, as well as the subtracted for error checking.  Here's the code:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static int d1 = 0;
        public static int d2 = 0;
        public static int d3 = 0;
        public static int d4 = 0;

        public static int sum = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void form_description_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void roll_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Random random_number = new Random();
            d1 = random_number.Next(1, 7);
            d2 = random_number.Next(1, 7);
            d3 = random_number.Next(1, 7);
            d4 = random_number.Next(1, 7);

            sum = Math.Min(Math.Min(Math.Min(d1, d2), d3), d4);

            label_d1.Text = "Value of D1 is:  " + d1;
            label_d2.Text = "Value of D2 is:  " + d2;
            label_d3.Text = "Value of D3 is:  " + d3;
            label_d4.Text = "Value of D4 is:  " + d4;
            label_sum.Text = "Value of Sum is:  " + sum;


            attribute_roll.Text = "Your strength is: " + ((d1 + d2 + d3 + d4) - sum);
        }
    }
}
```

The program works, so I know I'm on the right track.  The problem I have is converting it into a class.  I've tried several times, over and over, and I get different errors everywhere I turn.  So for converting this program into a class, my key questions are:

1. Is it possible to use Random, a pre-existing class, in my own class?  Or do I need to declare that in the form itself?
2. If I use "public static int" in the class, will the values transfer to the method?  I've not understood clearly the difference between "public int" and "public static int"?

Comment: 1. Form1 is a class and you are using Random in it. If your new class cannot see Random you will need to reference the namespace that describes where Random is. 2. There are so many explanations of static vs instance variables online it's pointless writing one here. Google. Good luck!

Comment: Neil Thompson is correct, look up the difference between static and instance variables.  But I have to ask... what is `form_description_click` for?!  I smell an Easter egg ;)

Comment: In response to what "form_description_click" is ... I honestly don't remember.  Since I'm new, I generated the form, then wiped away stuff and rewrote it.  I'm new enough that if the line is there, and it doesn't cause an error, I don't want to risk one by deleting the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me answer your two questions exactly as you asked them:

1) It is possible to use `Random`in your class. It doesn't need to be in the form

2) You can use static variables from static and non-static methods, but you can't use non-static variables from static methods.

Thumbs up! The fact that you found out that classes might help in your situation is the first step to write better rpograms. Try to find a tutorial online which covers the principles of object oriented design. This is something you'll really benefit from, independent of the actual programming language.

My suggestion: invest 50$ for one month of unlimited [Pluralsight trainings](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses#csharp). Pick a *C# fundamentals* or *C# from scratch* course and follow the examples by re-implementing them.

Comment: Thanks for the link to Pluralsight.  I'm actually learning it from the "Head First C#" book (2nd Edition) that I picked up.  Unfortunately, the chapter on classes was (I felt) inadequate, which is why I'm spending my time creating a class hands-on.  Thanks for your insights.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** It's possible to use it in your own class, you'd just define it in the class scope.

```
class Foo
{
    Random rng = new Random();
    ...
}
```

**2.** Static members don't require an instance to be accessed, therefore they are global to the entire program, non-static members are tied to an instance.

```
class Foo
{
    public static int Bar = 42;
    public int Baz = 42;
}

Console.WriteLine( Foo.Bar ); //OK, static variables don't require the class to be instantiated.
Console.WriteLine( Foo.Baz ); //Error, Baz is not static.

Foo foo_instance = new Foo();
Console.WriteLine( foo_instance.Baz ); //OK
```

Note that because of this, changing a static variable from inside an instance method will change it globally as well.

```
class Foo
{
    public static int Bar = 42;

    public void Baz()
    {
        Bar = Bar + 1;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine( Foo.Bar ); //42

Foo foo_instance = new Foo();
foo_instance.Baz();

Foo foo_instance2 = new Foo();
foo_instance2.Baz();

Console.WriteLine( Foo.Bar ); //44
```

So the values of your `d1`, `d2`, `d3`, `d4`, and `sum` variables can be changed outside the main instance of `Form1` if you have multiple instances and cause unexpected results.

The `Random` class also resides in the `System` namespace, so if that's giving errors, you need to include `using System;` at the top of your file.

Comment: +1 for spelling it out for him even though there is more than enough info on this elsewhere =)

Comment: Thanks for the info on when static is used ... I did search around the NET for information, but that is the clearest answer I've seen.

Answer (score 0):

It took a lot of trial and error, but I managed to convert my code into a class.  Unfortunately, I'm not 100% sure I understand what I DID.  Here's the code for the class:

```
public class four_d6_less_one
    {
        ////Variables declared here.  
        public static int dice1;
        public static int dice2;
        public static int dice3;
        public static int dice4;

        public static int minus_low;

        public static int sum_dice;

        //This is the constructor
        public four_d6_less_one()
        {
            Random rand_dice = new Random();
            dice1 = rand_dice.Next(1, 7);
            dice2 = rand_dice.Next(1, 7);
            dice3 = rand_dice.Next(1, 7);
            dice4 = rand_dice.Next(1, 7);

            minus_low = Math.Min(Math.Min(Math.Min(dice1, dice2), dice3), dice4);

            sum_dice = dice1 + dice2 + dice3 + dice4 - minus_low;
        }
```

And here is the code for the form itself:

```
 private void roll_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            four_d6_less_one make_it_roll = new four_d6_less_one();

            label_d1.Text = "Value of D1 is:  " + four_d6_less_one.dice1;  //This is where dice1 goes
            label_d2.Text = "Value of D2 is:  " + four_d6_less_one.dice2;  //This is where dice2 goes
            label_d3.Text = "Value of D3 is:  " + four_d6_less_one.dice3;  //This is where dice3 goes
            label_d4.Text = "Value of D4 is:  " + four_d6_less_one.dice4;  //This is where dice4 goes
            label_sum.Text = "Value of Sum is:  " + four_d6_less_one.minus_low;  //This is where minus_sum goes
            attribute_roll.Text = "Your strength is: " + four_d6_less_one.sum_dice;  //This totals all variables and subtracts minus_sum

        }
```

Here's what I'm not sure I understand:

1. Why did I have to declare "make_it_roll" to make the code work? 
   Without that line, the form just displays null values.  Is it
   because I had to create a new instance of the class to activate it?
2. Why did I have to call variables by saying "four_d6_less_one.dice1"
   and so forth?  Why couldn't I just put "dice1" as a variable?
3. Was there a more efficient way to write this code (I'm sure there always
   is, but I'm wondering if I missed something).